# How to get all h4 elements from an homepage with Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, output

I wrote a code to scrape all `h4` elements from a homepage.

```
// Wikipedia is only an example.
browser.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")
time.sleep(5)
datei = open("bayern.csv", "a")
elems = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("h4.name")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem)
```

In my command line  I get this output:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="f1ef1ee5904aa8b3279e6bf9adb62d34", element="0.09001580038742651-1") >
```

But I want the content of all `h4` elements. Can you tell me why I get this strange output?

Comment: What strange output? Why do you think `h4.name` would match *all* h4 elements?

Comment: Yes i want to get the content of all h4 elements.
For Exampel:
    <h4 class="name">Max Mustermann</h4>
I want to get back Max Mustermann

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to print the web element itself, instead of the text it contains.

Try:

```
elems = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("h4.name")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.text)
```

Comment: I couldn't get users code to actually get any H4 elements, but `elms = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h2')` finds H2 headers, and then your `elem.text` works as expected.  beat me to the answer, :-)

Comment: @BrianW the URL is just a placeholder I think. :)

Answer (score 0):

for convenience, `webdriver` has a `find_elements_by_tag_name` method:

```
elems = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('h4')
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.text)
```